# What algorithms can group characters into words?

Tags: algorithm, nlp

I have some text generated by some lousy OCR software.

The output contains mixture of words and space-separated characters, which should have been grouped into words. For example,

```
Expr e s s i o n Syntax
S u m m a r y o f T e r minology
```

should have been

```
Expression Syntax
Summary of Terminology
```

What algorithms can group characters into words?

If I program in Python, C#, Java, C or C++, what libraries provide the implementation of the algorithms?

Thanks.

Comment: using some nltk corpus and checking for combinations could help. Not sure you will endup with exact result. This greedy approach might fail in case of words which are part of large words. However there is no way to deterministically choose large or part words. This could be a starting point I guess.

Comment: I feel your pain of using OCR. Have you though of using a dynamic-programming algorithm? The ultimate idea is to have the program make a decision on how to group, and these decision might have to be checked in a recursive manner with each iteration checking a word in an English dictionary to verify if it's a valid word.

Answer (score 4):

Minimal approach:

1. In your input, remove the space before any single letter words. Mark the final words created as part of this somehow (prefix them with a symbol not in the input, for example).
2. Get a dictionary of English words, sorted longest to shortest.
3. For each marked word in your input, find the longest match and break that off as a word. Repeat on the characters left over in the original "word" until there's nothing left over. (In the case where there's no match just leave it alone.)

---

More sophisticated, overkill approach:

The problem of splitting words without spaces is a real-world problem in languages commonly written without spaces, such as Chinese and Japanese. I'm familiar with Japanese so I'll mainly speak with reference to that.

Typical approaches use a dictionary and a sequence model. The model is trained to learn transition properties between labels - part of speech tagging, combined with the dictionary, is used to figure out the relative likelihood of different potential places to split words. Then the most likely sequence of splits for a whole sentence is solved for using (for example) the Viterbi algorithm.

Creating a system like this is almost certainly overkill if you're just cleaning OCR data, but if you're interested it may be worth looking into.

---

A sample case where the more sophisticated approach will work and the simple one won't:

- input: `Playforthefunofit`
- simple output: `Play forth efunofit` (`forth` is longer than `for`)
- sophistiated output: `Play for the fun of it` (`forth efunofit` is a low-frequency - that is, unnatural - transition, while `for the` is not)

You can work around the issue with the simple approach to some extent by adding common short-word sequences to your dictionary as units. For example, add `forthe` as a dictionary word, and split it in a post processing step.

Hope that helps - good luck!